# Can not receive all of request in web Api Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have an web api service, in which i should receive 25 million request unfortunately we just get 80000.

Please advise where should be the problem.

Comment: Uh, get more customers? I don't understand what your exact problem is....

Comment: I think you need more servers to serve this traffic

Comment: As per @piet.t, your question is not clear that its your code architecture problem or client is there but they cant get your web-api. if it is the problem that your sever is unable to process this huge amount of request then you need to apply NLB servers and for each servers, create more worker process than default.

Comment: I had implemented a web service that some other ones call it and send data in its body request and I receive them and insert in data base. they claimed that send 25000000 requests but I can see just 80000 requests in my data base. where is my problem? and how could I test these amount of requests as parallel?

Comment: "They send  25000000" I find this claim a bit suspicious but this all depends on the time period in witch the requests come. You can try to make a reverse proxy and monitor the requests and tests if they are in a valid format. You also have IIS logs if you are on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

i try to test it :

```
 Parallel.For(0, 1000000, i => {
```

var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL); request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
 var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 var responseString = newStreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(); });

after thread NO. 4200 error accured to send request. could it be caused by server iis config?